# How to find if one cell is not equal to the cell to the left?

Tags: excel, vba, function, loops, offset

I am trying to create a VBA function that loops through each cell in a range, checking if it is equal or not to the cell to the left of it, and if it is a certain color. If it's not equal to the left cell and is that certain color, it adds a number in the same row but a different column to a running sum.

For whatever reason, the condition of the left cell being equal to the current cell is not working: it will still include cells that are the same value as the cell to the left. How do I fix this?

```
Sub TestFormulas()
    Dim x As Long
    x = SumRenewed(Range("E2:E9000"))
    MsgBox (x)
End Sub

' This function checks cell color and adds it to a sum if it is a certain color.
' It also checks to see if the cell is the same as what's to the left of it. If it is the same, it gets omitted.
' This prevents unnecessary older irrelevant month from being included.
Function SumRenewed(rRng As Range)

    Dim lngSum As Long
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim lngSomething As Variant
    
    For Each cl In rRng
    
        intIndex = cl.Interior.ColorIndex
        
        If cl <> Left(cl, 1) And cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then '43 is the color index for light green
        lngSomething = CLng(Cells(cl.Row, 2))
        MsgBox (lngSomething)
        lngSum = WorksheetFunction.Sum(lngSomething, lngSum)
        lngSomething = CVar(lngSomething)
        End If
    Next cl
    SumRenewed = lngSum

End Function
```

I have tried numerous workarounds for offsets, assigning Left(cl, 1) to a variable and changing the data type, and Googled every which way I can think for 2.5 days.

Comment: Use [`Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset), not `Left`. `If cl.Value <> cl.Offset(,-1).Value`

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Column If Matching Criteria (Incl. `ColorIndex`)

[image]

**In VBA**

```vb
Sub TestFormulas()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("E2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim MySum As Double
    MySum = SumRenewed(rg, "D", "B", 43)
    
    MsgBox MySum

End Sub
```

**The Function**

```vb
Function SumRenewed( _
    ByVal SingleColumnRange As Range, _
    ByVal CompareColumnID As Variant, _
    ByVal SumColumnID As Variant, _
    ByVal SingleColumnColorIndex As Long) _
As Double
    Application.Volatile
   
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = SingleColumnRange.Columns(1)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(CompareColumnID)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = lrg.EntireRow.Columns(SumColumnID)
    'Debug.Print lrg.Address, crg.Address, srg.Address
        
    Dim lCell As Range ' Lookup cell
    Dim r As Long ' Range Row
    Dim lString As String ' Lookup String
    Dim cString As String ' Compare String
    Dim sValue As Variant ' Sum Value
    Dim Total As Double ' Total Sum
    
    For Each lCell In lrg.Cells
        r = r + 1
        lString = CStr(lCell.Value)
        cString = CStr(crg.Cells(r).Value)
        If StrComp(lString, cString, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' not equal
            If lCell.Interior.ColorIndex = SingleColumnColorIndex Then
                sValue = srg.Cells(r).Value
                'Debug.Print r, lString, cString, sValue
                If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                    Total = Total + sValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next lCell
    
    SumRenewed = Total

End Function
```

**In Excel (not recommended)**

- Note that it will update on each calculation due to `Application.Volatile`. It will never update if the color has changed. Hence it is practically useless in Excel.

```vb
=SumRenewed(E2:E21,"D","B",43)
```